# How does Twitter Bootstrap collapsing work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been toying around with the [Twitter Bootstrap website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html), and I'm intrigued by how the top navigation bar collapses into a different layout when you shrink the browser window.

This is what it looks like expanded:

[image: Twitter Bootstrap bar expanded]

And this is what it looks like when collapsed:
[image: Twitter Bootstrap bar collapsed]

How is it doing this?

Comment: How about using Firebug to find out?

Comment: @UweKeim Wow, since when did Stackoverflow become this hostile? I really like how you assumed I didn't try that already.

Comment: Then which detail did you not understand? The more specific your question, the more probable a useful answer.

Comment: @DennisTraub Having a bad night as well? I think I clearly asked how Bootstrap was collapsing the top toolbar into a different layout. There's even pretty pictures for you to see that.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine, thank you.

Comment: @DennisTraub That's unfortunate.

Comment: @Sam I think the more you show in your question that you put effort in solving the issue, the more you would attract others to help you. At least I try to do it in this way when asking questions.

Comment: @Sam you are right. Don't worry. Some people do not know how to well use their time. I am asking myself the same, I want to find out what js function triggers the collapse of the navbar. This post sooner or later will receive a nice reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does the changes by media queries. CSS3 allows media dependent style-sheet by media (viewport?) and detect things such as width/height

More reading on media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries
I had a glance to their css, but u can get a hint at the page css source: **bootstrap-responsive.css**

I believe bootstrap promotes responsive design with their toolkit as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I will look into this and see if I can find what I need to know! +1