# Bootstrap JQuery loading twice - Navbar not collapsing in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello my fellow rails developers,

This is a weird one. My Bootstrap Navbar won't collapse in mobile view; rather when I relaunch the rails server and refresh the view, the navbar shows in a collapsed state for half a second and then returns to expanded mode.

It looks like Jquery might be loading twice or might be loading properly after being erased/overriden by another setting of my app. Which I can't figure out...

Gemfile:

```
ruby "2.4.1"
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import url("header.scss");
@import url("footer.scss");
@import url("background.scss");


/* Remove the required * next to email field */
abbr[title="required"] {
  display: none;
} .....
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require smooth_scroll
//= require_tree .
```

I have followed the procedure as per the official [documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

The only potentially conflicting actions was that I initially installed Bootstrap 4.0 but had to downgrade to Bootstrap 3.0 as the simple_form gem is not compatible with Bootstrap 4.0 at this time. It was working fine before with Bootstrap 4.

live version of the app can be seen [Here](https://jbts2018.herokuapp.com/)

How can I spot the issue? Many thanks indeed

Comment: I have not problem with a nav menu for mobile on your site. But seems like header, footer and background css files not compiling to the application css and loads separately

Comment: Thanks for your observation Kolas. However I have the feeling it's more a JS/JQuery issue...

Comment: Hello, I updated my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569521/how-does-twitter-bootstrap-collapsing-work#10569599)

Bootstrap create that navbar collapse effect with media queries

> CSS3 allows media dependent style-sheet by media (viewport?) and detect things such as width/height
>
> More reading on media query at the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries):

Now you can go and test/check the css and @media queries performed in the following [navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/)

You can see that the navbar has two main componenents, those that will always be displayed:

```
<div class='navbar-header'></div>
```

and those that will be hidden when the viewport is smaller then `750px`

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
```

if you check the `css` property of the first `div` you see that it has `display:block`, while the second one has the following css styles:

When the page width is wider then `768px` it will have property `display: block!important;`

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
```

This property will be lost from this `div` when the `width` is lower then `768px`, then another property will be applied based on the `class collapse` that `div` has.

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

`display:none` will hide those `divs` and make your `navbar` responsive

This property is included in row `3462` of `bootstrap.css`

So what is your problem (I am boring, I know :-) )

### What is the problem

This is the `html` code for your `div`

```
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse'></div>
```

This is the `css` style of that `div`.

At row `4534` you have a media query with `min-width:768px` that should not be applied. As you can see from the code, this media query change `display: none` to `display:block !important`

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
}

application-8e3…bc19c7f7.css:5
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

but this should not be happening because the `window` width now is at `337px`. I don't really know the clear solution to this, but I can tell you.

You can print the `screen` js variable on the console and read more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

So If my page width is set at `475px` with the developer toolbar, then I go to the console and input `screen`

```
screen
Screen {availWidth: 475, availHeight: 893, width: 475, height: 893, colorDepth: 24, …}
```

So the width is `475` like in my developer console, so what I am thinking is, the js effect is not running because js is broken. It is not responsive because js is not triggered.

### Solution

You can solve this problem by adding in your `application.html.erb` file the following `html` code

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
</head>
```

I tested this on your page and the problem is fixed as you can see from the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hello Fabrizio. This is indeed JS which is broken but I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I have followed the Bootstrap-Sass gem documentation precisely. :(  Thanks for helping though :)

Comment: @RodolpheGeant you are not using `jquery-ujs` still.. that is mostly used to make your rails erb `forms` work.  then also I quote `Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.`

Comment: @RodolpheGeant Your best option is just manually include in your folders the bootstrap files and include them in your asset pipeline. You need all the js and css files.

Comment: @RodolpheGeant also follow the `jquery-rails` documentation https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Comment: Good tip. I Will do this and let you know if it fixes it. Thanks again :)

Comment: After all I'm not sure if it's loading twice. What it does is , it's loading for half a second normally (collapsed) and then revert to uncollapsed. I have looked into copying manually the Bootstrap filed locally but I'm not comfortable doing it; it looks cumbersome and it's very confusing for me. Maybe I'm better off rebuilding the app from the ground up....  unless you have a link that describes the procedure ?

Comment: @RodolpheGeant I believe this is your real problem **Why media queries are not working** https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+media+queries+are+not+working&atb=v52-6_b&ia=qa

Comment: you don't need to do anything @RodolpheGeant because I solved your problem. You can read the solution. You need to include `<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
</head>` I updated my question. Read the `Solution` paragraph

Comment: Hello Fabrizio. This is what I get from the Chrome inspector https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbx91nwhy86otcx/BS3.JPG?dl=0
Same problem on IOS device (Iphone 7+) . I havent tested on Samsung but I the feeling it might be an IOS problem.....

Comment: @RodolpheGeant this problem is solved. I attached you screenshot of your webpage working. Please accept my answer as the answer clearly solved your problem and send me a link to your new issue. For mobile devices you need to do remote debugging as from the chrome developers tolls documentation https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3 this way you can see the html in the mobile device page. 
you need to open a new issue for this new problem, as it is specific for IOS devices.

Comment: furthermore, In the application.html.erb file there was already that line in the <head> section:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
I replaced it with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> just to be sure.... but no luck :(

Comment: @RodolpheGeant splitting problems in small steps is the best way to get a solution. We need to do brainstorming and the best way is having a whole new question describing this issue. Send me the link I will help you

Comment: @RodolpheGeant you do not have those meta tags in the `<head>`. Inspect your page. Either accept my answer or do not write me anymore. I don't have time to read this and I dedicated to much time to you. If you write me I will flag you.

Comment: yup you are right. I was missing that line! Thank you. Have a nice day. I will help you when I'm a star Rails developer. I promise :)

Comment: @RodolpheGeant yes, in few months you will code apps in 1 week... don't worry.. unluckly here there are many issue so I need to solve as many as I can.. so I'm a little bit in a hurry. thanks a lot

Comment: I understand man, no worries. You take care and thank you once more :)